# Как в python приклеить цифру к букве без пробела?

Tags: python

Есть такая строка

```py
print (hour, '-й час')
```

как сделать так, чтобы выводилось без пробела?

Выводится: `1 -й час`

Нужно: `1-й час`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f-строка, очевидно поможет

```py
hour = 10

print(f"{hour}-й час")
```

Comment: большое спасибо!